# Use JS to add characters into textfield

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to add a $ symbol before a users entry into a text field without actually submitting the $ when the user clicks submit. Additionally, I need to prohibit the user from entering anything but numerical values in to the text input. I know about the JQuery input mask ([http://www.conetrees.com/2009/03/blog/jquery-masked-input-plugin-increase-usability-for-masked-format-input-fields](http://www.conetrees.com/2009/03/blog/jquery-masked-input-plugin-increase-usability-for-masked-format-input-fields/)) but this plugin requires you to set the exact number of digits/letters that the user is supposed to enter, which is no good for my current project. Can anyone think of a way to accomplish what I have described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to grab everything except for the dollar from the input, and store it in a hidden field:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var total = $("#total").val();
    $("#hidden").val(total.replace("$", ""));
});
```

Here's a full working solution (bear in mind, it probably needs refinement before it meets the real world):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var total = $(".total").val();
    $("#hidden").val(total.replace("$", ""));
});
$("#total").keypress(function() {
    validateNumeric();
}).keyup(function() {

    // if the user has pressed backspace and removed the dollar, put it back
    if($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val("$");
    }
});

function validateNumeric(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    if(key == 8) {
        return true;
    }
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = /[0-9]/;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Test markup:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="total" value="$"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: But, how would I display the character when the user inputs some text into the field?

Answer (score 1):

If the $ will always be there, how about putting it *before* the text field?

Personally I avoid inserting extraneous things (units, watermarks, whatnot) into the value of a text field like the plague. They always end up getting interpreted as actual content in ways they're not supposed to.

Comment: One of those 'must have' demands by the client that the $ appear in the field once the user clicks on the text input. I know its totally nuts.

Comment: Also there is another part of the form where the client wants to append 'sq.feet' to the end of the user's input.

Comment: Slap some sense into your client. Tell him it's the same as having the field labels appear only when they're clicked, which is a nasty variation of Mystery Meat Navigation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation)

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. He's got this retarded cocktail napkin mockup that he wants to adhere to 100% and a 'I could do it if I wanted too' attitudes about web design. You can thank oDesk for this kind of nonsense.

Comment: idea: put left-padding on the input and overlay a span with `$` in it on top. Then it looks like it's part of the input, but doesn't take part in editing.

Comment: I played around with the borders and padding for a long time to see if I could get that kind of solution to work but IE alignment issues made it really messy.